# How to check EditText selection position in more than one?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-cursor

I have three EditText in android.

When I click cancel Button (cursor position is located in first EditText) - it hides the SoftKeyboard. That's OK.

But when I click cancel Button (cursor position is located in second EditText) - it doesn't hide SoftKeyboard.

```
hideSoftKeyboard(edt_category_name); 
hideSoftKeyboard(edt_category_price); 
hideSoftKeyboard(edt_category_qty);
```

...

```
btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               hideSoftKeyboard(edt_category_name); // check condition here;
               dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used below code to hide KeyBoard :

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edt_category_name.getWindowToken(), 0);
                           }
        });
```

Comment: Yes, I use. If not, why first EditText hides the SoftKeyboard?

Comment: Can you please share your code? where you have used this code and button click event.

Comment: Plz, check my question (Edited)

Comment: Just try one thing. Don't call 'hideSoftKeyboard()'  method, directly hide `SoftKeyboard` from button click and pass any of the `EditText` object. It is working from my side.
See my edit

Comment: hideSoftKeyboard(edt_category_name); // check condition here;

Check condition for what??
To hide `softkeyboard` no need to pass different `widget` object, but by passing only 1 `widget` object the`softkeyboard` will get hidden.

Comment: Welcome.. Glad that it helped you. Mark this answer as accepted if it worked for you..